# How to completely close MongoDB connection+socket in node-mongodb-native 3.1?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

**In short:** When I try to close the MongoDB connection in Node.js, the MonogDB driver seems to close the connection itself as expected but something in the background seems to wait for a socket until it times out (or so), which prevents things like Jest to end cleanly.

**Deatils:**

I'm using NPM packages `"mongodb": "^3.1.11"` (Node.js MongoDB Driver 3.1) and `"jest": "^23.6.0"` and I am aware that you should close the connection after the tests have completed.

The [MongoDB example by Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/docs/MongoDB.md) currently seems to relate to Node.js MongoDB Driver 2.x, and Version 3 no longer has a `db.close()` method.

Here's my simple test file:

```
// example.test.js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let client;
let db;

beforeAll(async () => {
    client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    db = await client.db('testdb');
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await client.close(); // Returns successfully
});

it('should insert and find document', async () => {
    const collection = db.collection('files');
    await collection.insert({name: 'Jest'});
    const doc = await collection.findOne({name: 'Jest'});
    expect(doc._id).toBeDefined();
    expect(doc.name).toBe('Jest');
});
```

After the test completes the MongoDB connection is apparently successfully closed. I can even confirm this by checking a MongoDB server log (`end connection 127.0.0.1:33312 (0 connections now open)`), yet Jest still refuses to end the process. The recommended Jest CLI option `--detectOpenHandles` does not output anything.

I realised that after 6 minutes Jest will end successfully after all; 6 minutes === 360000 milliseconds, which happens to be the default value for `socketTimeoutMS` of the `MongoClient.connect` [options](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html).

If I set a custom value for `socketTimeoutMS`, Jest will complete after the specified time. Edit test file from above:

```
// ...
beforeAll(async () => {
    client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        socketTimeoutMS: 1000, // <----- insert this line
    });
    db = await client.db('testdb');
});
// ...
```

Now, Jest will complete after a delay of only 1 second instead of 6 minutes.

I don't know what the socket timeout really does here and why the MongoDB driver waits for the socket to time out after closing the connection. It could be a bug in the driver or it could be me doing something wrong.

I also figured out that using the `force` option of the `close` method (`client.close(true)`) seems to resolve the issue locally (MacOS), but unfortunately not on the CI server (Linux/Docker). The same is the case for Jest CLI option `--forceExit`.

**Any ideas how I can close the MongoDB connection cleanly?**

Comment: If MongoDB reports the connection is closed, it's likely that the issue was jest cannot proceed past a certain point. Are you seeing the message `Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.`? There seems to be some issues running jest when watchman is running: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#watchman-issues

Comment: Fwiw, I can see the `Jest did not exit...` message intermittently. I've been unable to determine the exact cause. It's probably worth noting that currently once I'm able to induce the `Jest did not exit...` message, I'm unable to get rid of it now.

Comment: Just to give you an update, I seem to be able to get rid of the message using `yarn test --no-cache`

Comment: i have the same problem, it seems the mongodb module opens one connection for the MongoClient object, and another one for the DB object, if it is used, closing the client will not close the DB, and at least with version 3.5.2 will cause warnings. im looking at the source code for the module hoping i will find a good solution